# In Jquery get attribute of targeted element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to replace all divs with the class data-item with the attribute data-variable of the item with this class

IE :

```
<div class="data-item" data-variable="{{somevariable}}">
  Some Content
</div> 

<div class="data-item" data-variable="{{someothervariable}}">
  Some Content
</div>
```

Should become

```
{{somevariable}}{{someothervariable}}
```

Code I want to use:

```
$( "div.data-item" , el ).replaceWith( get the data-variable attribute of this element);
```

where el is a jquery object containing the html I wish to parse

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/, http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/my2ghq7k/)

```
$( "div.data-item").each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).data('variable'));
})
```

**UPD:** You can use function as argument to `replaceWith` (thx @Barmar)

```
$('div.data-item').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).data('variable');
});
```

Comment: Thanks will accept this as it helped me with the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `replaceWith` can be a function. When it's called, `this` will be the element that's being replaced. The return value will be used as the replacement.

```
$("div.data-item").replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-variable");
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works just as well. Wondering if there is any performance difference in the solutions as marsh answer uses .each.

Comment: They should be pretty similar. jQuery is just doing the `.each` loop internally.